# Change the size of blue dot in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I've used `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` to show my location on Google Maps. Now the problem is that it is showing the blue dot but is it too small, how can I change the size of default that blue dot?

I reached to a point that I could change it by creating another class, but I just want to change the size and I don't want to create another pointer

Comment: Currently, not possible. You may want to file a feature request regarding this in Google Public Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188870&template=788012